# Routing with areas using prefix or not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my app I have two areas: `Portal` and `Admin`. I want to configure routes in `XXXAreaRegistration.cs` files.

What I want is `/{controller}/{action}` for the `Portal` and `/admin/{controller}/{action}` for the `Admin` panel.

I tried the configuration below to make it possible:

```
// AdminAreaRegistration.cs
context.MapRoute("Admin",
                 "admin/{controller}/{action}",
                 new { action = "Index", controller = "Admin" });

// PortalAreaRegistration.cs
context.MapRoute("Portal",
                 "{controller}/{action}",
                 new { action = "Index", controller = "Portal" });
```

For `/` I get my `Portal/Index.cshtml`, but for `/admin` I get `404`... I suppose in the second case it looks for `AdminController` in `Portal` area and that's why I get `404`. But how to make a workaround to create such a routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the routing collision that you currently have add a constraint to your Portal area registration:

```
// PortalAreaRegistration.cs
context.MapRoute(
    "Portal",
    "{controller}/{action}",
    new { action = "Index", controller = "Portal" },
    new { controller = "^(?!.*admin).*$" }
);
```

This will ensure that the Portal area will be mapped to everything `{controller}/{action}` except for `admin/*` because you want this served by the Admin area.

Of course for more than obvious reasons you cannot have a controller called `AdminController` in your Portal area.

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 1):

in your code when you call http://www.domain.com/admin/ your routing searching as http://www.domain.com/admin/admin because your default controller is admin set default parameter as existing control

i guess there is no controll in area called such as admin

*UPTADE FOR NAME SPACE*

fix code like at below

```
 context.MapRoute("Admin",
             "admin/{controller}/{action}",
             new { action = "Index", controller="Home"},
             new string[] { "MyApp.Admin.Controllers" }  // specify the new namespace);
```